# Care of Brain cells as per scriptures

Tags: scripture

I understand that scriptures show various ways of the Mind's spiritual progression. Although, what are the various things that scriptures mention about taking care of physical Brain cells? Like keeping the brain cells healthy and their regeneration. Any measures and actions?